# How can I add the sklearn-pipeline on explainer dashboard

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Using pipeline `from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline`, I managed to build and save a model. My problem is I cant load to the pipeline into the explainer dashaboard
`from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard`.

here are the parameters for the explainer dashboard.

`explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)`

- on model I can train a new model object with `pipeline.fit()`
- My problem is X_train and Y_train. Without the pipeline I setup earlier
  place, I can't correctly process do the data preaparation for X.

What can we do to use the pipeline with explainer dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember we had to use the model like this:

```
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model.fit, X_test, y_test)
```

such thing is also mentioned in the provider's documentation [enter link description here](https://explainerdashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: if both x and y is transformed by pipeline, how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade scikit-learn to version 1.1.1 (which is only supported on python 3.8 or higher). See documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_1_0.html#get-feature-names-out-available-in-all-transformers)

If you are using Google Colab this wont work unfortunately as it is still running on python3.7 (as at 2022.07.31) and hence scikit-learn 1.0 which doesn't support 'get_feature_names_out' in pipelines.